# Function template failing in clang

Tags: c++, clang

I have this section of code that was previously compiling fine with the Microsoft compiler. I have now switched to clang and am receiving the following errors:

> Error 16 error : expected member name or ';' after declaration
>   specifiers'

-

> Error 15 error : expected a qualified name after 'typename'

for the line of code

```
template<typename PRIM> typename const PRIM::OutputPtrType          GetData(unsigned long index = 0) const;
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch your `typename const` to `const typename`.

```
template<typename PRIM> const typename PRIM::OutputPtrType          GetData(unsigned long index = 0) const;
```

The [C++ Grammar rules for `templates`](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram.temp) has an entry for `typename` which dictates:

> *typename...<sub>opt</sub> identifier<sub>opt</sub>.*
>
> *typename nested-name-specifier identifier*

`const` isn't an `identifier` rather a *`cv-qualifier`*. An identifier in your context is a dependent name. which is basically `PRIM::OutputPtrType`, since `OutputPtrType` will depend on the name `PRIM`. For the second line, we can more accurately say that `PRIM::` is a nested-name-specifier.

**EDIT**

> [**$14.6:1**](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#3) When a qualified-id is intended to refer to a type that is not a
>   member of the current instantiation ([[temp.dep.type]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.type)) and its
>   nested-name-specifier refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed
>   by the keyword typename, forming a typename-specifier. If the
>   qualified-id in a typename-specifier does not denote a type, the
>   program is ill-formed.
>
> > ```
> > typename-specifier:
> >   typename nested-name-specifier identifier
> >   typename nested-name-specifier templateopt simple-template-id
> > ```

Answer (score 2):

You have to move `const` to the right:

```
template<typename PRIM>
typename PRIM::OutputPtrType const GetData(unsigned long index = 0) const;
                             ^^^^^
```

Or to the left:

```
template<typename PRIM>
const typename PRIM::OutputPtrType GetData(unsigned long index = 0) const;
^^^^^
```

In this context after the `typename` keyword the compiler expects a qualified name.

Comment: @marsh which compiler?

Comment: Microsoft C/C++ Compiler

Comment: @marsh You need to ask Microsoft why their compiler accepts clearly invalid code.